# How come Minion is such a hassle to use in pdfLatex when Palatino isn't?

Tags: fonts, packages

Palatino (or some copy of it) is very easy to use in pdfLatex -- just use package `mathpazo` and you're set to go.

How come Minion doesn't have such an easy-to-use package? I tried to install it using a step-by-step guide, but in the end it complained about missing some font file. And it took me a couple of hours just to get there.

Comment: There is a package for pdfLaTeX called `MinionPro`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Palatino font used with LaTeX is actually a free clone. As a result, both the font itself and the support files can be included directly in TeX distributions. It is this clone that is loaded by

```
\usepackage{mathpazo}
```

On the other hand, Minion Pro is a commercial font. As Philipp points out, there is a [package containing the support files](http://ctan.org/pkg/minionpro) that you can download from CTAN. However, that still requires the fonts themselves.

The need for font metric files is a difficult when using TeX, which is why most people are moving to using either XeTeX or LuaTeX when they want to load system fonts. The [`fontspec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) package makes this easy in LaTeX, and so most of us would avoid the issues with generating font metric files for pdfTeX nowadays.

Comment: Yeah, I guess the only viable option is to use XeLaTeX. Have never used or even heard of it before I visited this site. Will give that a try. Thanks.

Comment: @gablin: If you only want to use Minion Pro and nothing else (Unicode, support for arbitrary OpenType fonts, …), the `MinionPro` package should actually do the job.

Comment: @Philipp: The problem is that it doesn't include the actual fonts, which is what I'm having trouble with installing.

Answer (score 6):

You could produce very neat document using Minion Pro and Myriad Pro (for *sans serif*) through [XeLaTeX](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=xetex). This doesn't affect the main structure of your Latex file. Here is an example of a preamble that you can use:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
%\usepackage{sectsty}  
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}  
\usepackage[english]{babel}   
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage[margin=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
%\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,backref=true]{biblatex}
%\bibliography{refs}

\def\myauthor{...}
\def\mytitle{...}
\def\mycopyright{\myauthor}
\def\mykeywords{...}

\setmainfont[Mapping={tex-text},Numbers={OldStyle},Ligatures={Common}]{Minion Pro} 
\setsansfont[Mapping={tex-text},Scale=0.9]{Myriad Pro}
\setmonofont[Mapping=tex-text,Colour=AA0000,Scale=0.9]{Inconsolata} 

\title{\mytitle}
\author{\myauthor}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

text here

\end{document}
```

To compile, you just have to run `xelatex` on it.